# Size of an AlertDialog with an ImageView is too large

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

**Context**

I would like to have an AlertDialog with a square sized image. My images are sized 800x800 pixels, which is larger than the device screen (800x480). The image scales automatically to the size of the AlertDialog. However, the Dialog itself gets too large: it is the complete height of the app.

**Problem**

I would like to have the dialog only occupy the space of the image (plus the dialog button). Why does this not happen? I thought Dialogs are standard set to WRAP_CONTENT.

**Code:**

```
ImageView photo = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageof800x800pixels)
AlertDialog.Builder builder =
new AlertDialog.Builder(HangboardActivity.this).
      //setMessage(R.string.nextgrip). // this is quite ugly
      setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           dialog.dismiss();
      }
      }).
      setView(photo);
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

**Edited Code**:

```
            ImageView photo = findPhotoForExercise();

            int widthPX = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int heightPX = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthPX, heightPX);
            photo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(HangboardActivity.this).
                            setMessage(R.string.nextgrip). // this is quite ugly
                            setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).
                            setView(photo);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

Comment: downscale the image. Is this an option?

Comment: That works (I already tested that), but it is not a great solution since on screens with more pixels (e.g. tablets) you would like to have the higher resolution of the image (as the dialog can be larger).

Comment: ... Which you can also solve by programatically looking for the width of the device. I hoped it should be possible to solve this in a more elegant way. I think this issue might be due to that the Dialog is created first with the full size of the image in mind, and the image is then scaled  to fit inside the dialog, yet the dialog size itself is not updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your first shot would be scale down the image to be small enough to fit inside your dialog, but if that isn't good enough you can set it's height and width in density pixels to respect all screen sizes with a fixed size.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsL = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsL);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
int widthPX = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 400, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int heightPX = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 400, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthPX, heightPX);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
layout.addView(photo);
```

I advise against using the layout progrmatically because you can do a xml layout that has an imageview which has its layout_width and layout_height been in fixed dp like above and that would do the exact behavior as doing it programatically like mentioned above.
I think the xml layouts is a good practice because you will have all your layouts in one place and it's more readable and also you can have different layouts for different screen resolutions (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) and different device configuration(portrait, landscape) and many more advantages

Comment: Setting a fixed size for the ImageView before building the Dialog sounds like a good solution. However, it did not work for me as expected: see the edited code above. This still makes the dialog to expand over the full height, while the image does not occupy that space. I set 200x200 pixels as that gave a good result when I downscaled the image to that size.

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot for your help. Why do you actually advise against a programmatical setting? Since I did not make an XML for this Dialog, I find it easier not to use an XML when it is not necessary.

Comment: It's a good practice because you will have all your layouts in one place and it's more readable and also you can have different layouts for different screen resolutions (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) and different device configuration(portrait, landscape) and many more advantages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do:

```
ImageView photo = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageof800x800pixels);
photo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(DESIRED_WIDTH,DESIRED_HEIGHT));
```

note that the class LayoutParams is nested in multiple View Classes, so it depends on your need, eg. if your ImageView is inside a Linear Layout you should do something like this:

```
photo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DESIRED_WIDTH,DESIRED_HEIGHT));
```

Now for the desired width and height, you can set them programatically:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int DESIRED_WIDTH = (int) diplay.getWidth() * PERCENTAGE;
int DESIRED_HEIGHT = (int) display.getHeight() * PERCENTAGE;
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the code to find the device width. Works perfectly now together with the code in the other answer.